# Select next 50000 entries

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I selected the first 50,000 rows with `TOP 50,000`, now I want to get the next group of 50,000. I can't use `ROW_NUMBER` since the entries do not have an `id`. I use SQL Server 2012 with the help of SQL Server Management Studio.

How can I get the entries that come after the first 50,000?

Comment: If you selected `top 50000` without an `ORDER BY` on some column (such as the `id` that you say is absent), then there's no guarantee that even re-running the *same* query will return the *same* 50000 rows - let alone any way to guarantee being able to obtain the "next" 50000.

Answer (score 4):

With SQL Server 2012, you get the next `OFFSET` and `FETCH NEXT` keywords on the `ORDER BY` clause.

So you can select the first 50'000 rows with:

```
SELECT (list of columns)
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE (some condition)
ORDER BY (some column)
  OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50000 ROWS ONLY
```

and then the next 50'000 later with:

```
SELECT (list of columns)
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE (some condition)
ORDER BY (some column)
  OFFSET 50000 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50000 ROWS ONLY
```

(*just a side-note: a page size of **50'000 rows** seems overly large - how about 1'000 or something?*)

See [Using the new OFFSET and FETCH NEXT options](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2012/using-new-offset-and-fetch-next-options) for more details and background info

Answer (score 0):

If you have some way to assure a consistent order of the results I can't see why you can't use row_number with a common table expression like this:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY something_unique DESC) AS 'Row'
    FROM my_table   
)
-- To get the first 50k rows:
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE Row BETWEEN 0 AND 50000 
-- To get the next 50k rows:
--SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE Row BETWEEN 50001 AND 100000
```

It's not very effecient though as you construct the row number over the whole table even though you only need 50k. If possible you might want to consider adding an extra column to the source table to include some artifical numering.

As noted in the comments just using TOP X without ordering the results first will render inconsistent results as order isn't guaranteed if not explicitly specified.